# Do dlls always get loaded in the same way into a process?

Tags: windows, dll, portable-executable, pdb-files, ntdll

I am trying to build a mini-profiler.
It records function calls for a given set of tests and is supposed to later tell which functions from a given module were run.

I record a bunch of virtual addresses which I can convert to pairs of [module name, address offset] cheaply.

It is a very expensive operation to load PDBs in every process and query it symbol names.

I am thinking of saving down the list of [module name, address offset], then load the PDBs in a post-processing program and map these to symbols just once.

Now I am not sure whether modules/dlls get always loaded in the same way, i.e. the virtual address offset of a symbol from the module base is always the same?

Is it also the same if the module (same binary dll) gets loaded on different Windows editions (e.g. Win7 vs WinServer2008)?

Comment: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: @HansPassant does this apply just to the module base or also to the sections?
What if I compile with these options explicitly disabled?

Comment: Sections have a fixed offset from the module base.  /DYNAMICBASE is not the only reason, a DLL also gets relocated if its preferred base address is not available for whatever reason.  There's just no point in trying to avoid loading the PDB, a profiler that doesn't generate the function name is too mini to be useful.

Comment: @HansPassant In my project I have so many modules that it takes 10 minutes to load all PDBs. A lot of my tests only run for 1-2 minutes. I want to outsource loading the PDBs into a single after-all-tests task.

Comment: 10 minutes is well beyond absurd, somebody would have noticed a long time ago that debugging this code became impractical.  The most obvious cause are network timeouts, caused by a bad source server setting.